# Preventing Visual Studio making focus on the new tab opened while start debugging

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, debugging, firefox

Is is possible to prevent Visual Studio making focus on the new tab opened while I start debugging (F5) in a web application Asp.Net Mvc?

I use FireFox (The latest version to date)

Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Why do you want that? Can you explain your reasoning and maybe that can lead to an answer more direct to your problem.

Comment: Hi @Justin, sometime, I read an article while programming and I go Visual studio pressing F5 to start debugging and while Visual studio builds the solution, I return reading my article. A couple of seconds later while I'm still reading the article, the focus is set the a new tab where my application running.

Comment: Yes, that is because your program (the web app) started. It would do the same thing if it was not a web app. Once it is done building, it loads your application to the top of the z order.